# SELECT RECORD FROM ORACLE DATABASE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract the "last" inserted record from database, using this type of query

```
SELECT A.IDOC_NUM, A.SEG_NUM
FROM  AGR3PL_LINE A, AGR3PL_IDOC B
WHERE A.IDOC_NUM(+) = B.IDOC_NUM
AND B.IDOC_NUM = '457154' AND B.CREATION_DATE = (SELECT MAX(B.CREATION_DATE) FROM AGR3PL_IDOC B)
ORDER BY A.SEG_NUM DESC;
```

The result is this:

```
IDOC_NUM SEG_NUM
457154     9
457154     8
457154     7
457154     6
457154     5
457154     4
457154     3
457154     2
457154     10
457154     1
```

This is correct, but the entry 10 is last entered, but as you can see the format result is not good, it sholud be 10,9,8..., is it maybe problem with datebase or somethig else???

Comment: is SEG_NUM set up as a VARCHAR instead of a numeric? It looks to be doing a string sort, not a numeric sort. Change the column definition, or cast/convert the `ORDER BY A.SEG_NUM` value.

Comment: it's varchar, so I need to use order by?

Comment: You do still need to use order_by, but you have to let the query know to sort it by those values as if they are numeric, not a string. Take a look at some of the other answers below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(A.SEG_NUM) DESC;
```

Comment: Don't live with bad design. Correct it ! (when a field is called xx_NUM)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus man, this is so right, but I'm no teacher around here I'm just answering questions... plus you don't even know if he has the possibility of changing it...

Comment: @Sebas, I know I know, one day I answer, the other I give lessons ;)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus haha nice idea actually! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, SEG_NUM is stored as a "string" type (VARCHAR2 or anohter).

Set the column type as NUMBER, and sort will be fine.

Comment: I cant change the type, I can just convert it to number

Comment: +1 for the "Correct" answer. The right answer is to always fix the root of the problem! However, depending on the the use of the column and if he has access to change the column type, you should mention converting/casting the value to a number for the correct sort. :)

Comment: I let him choose what he really wants and stay psychorigid ;)

Answer (score 2):

Probably `SEG_NUM` is text type (e.g. `VARCHAR`), so it is not sorted like a number.

You can change type of this column (it is the best solution, because if it is number it should have numeric type) or you can convert this column type during execution (it can reduce performance):

```
SELECT A.IDOC_NUM, A.SEG_NUM 
FROM  AGR3PL_LINE A, AGR3PL_IDOC B 
WHERE A.IDOC_NUM(+) = B.IDOC_NUM 
AND B.IDOC_NUM = '457154' AND B.CREATION_DATE = (SELECT MAX(B.CREATION_DATE) FROM AGR3PL_IDOC B) 
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(A.SEG_NUM) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for also pointing out that the convert will work for his case, but that it can affect performance. In this case, probably not so much. But if he has 100,000+ rows... that might show. Adding a degree of N to the runtime...

Answer (score 1):

the problem seem to be SEG_NUM is varchar in ur case. So it is treating 10 lower than 2.

Do it this way -

```
ORDER BY to_number(A.SEG_NUM) DESC
```